# Font family in Text Input React native

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to implement a text input, where the font family is Zila Slab Bold, But the font family only works for the place holder of the text input, It doesn't work for the inputted text instead it shows the default android text, but when I use Zila Slab Medium it works for both the placeholder and Inputted text, Please what may  I be doing wrong, I'm using RN 0.55.0

This is what I want to get

[image]

This is what I get when I use `Zila Bold`

[image]

This is my code below

```
<TextInput    
       underlineColorAndroid={'transparent'}
       placeholder="The Title"
                  placeholderStyle={{fontFamily: 'ZillaSlab-Bold',
            fontSize: 16,}}
                  placeholderTextColor="rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)"
style={{
                      paddingLeft: 28,
                      width: (Dimensions.get('window').width),
                      backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                      fontSize: 16, color: 'black',
                      borderTopWidth: 2, borderBottomWidth: 2, borderColor: 'black', 
            marginTop: 100, flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center', fontFamily: 'ZillaSlab-Bold',
                  }}/>
```

Comment: do you want to use same font for both ?

Comment: Yes,  I want to use the same font for both

Answer (score 4):

The solution proposed by [Люда Дзюбинска](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61488413/937133) didn't work for me, but similar approach did the trick - I've specified `fontWeight: 'normal'` style for `TextInput` field (even though I had a semibold font) and it let me avoid resetting font family upon input.

Comment: what is this sorcery! This worked for me thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I have this issue with react-native version 62 and for me solution was to add fontStyle: "normal"

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a react native bug.
See: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/18820

Comment: I went to the link, They were not able to come up with a solution